# regex expression using str_extract_all

Tags: r, regex

The following regex search is giving incorrect results for certain strings.

```
str_extract_all("This Dose was given to him in the U.S. on 16 June",regex("(\\b(Baseline)\\b|\\b(Table)\\b|\\b(U.S.)\\b|\\b(D.S.)\\b)",ignore_case = TRUE))
```

It outputs `Dose` as a matched pattern based on D.S which it should not.
However, it does not match `U.S.` which is part of the pattern and present in the text.

I have provided `\\b\\b` so that exact block of the pattern is searched.

Anything incorrect in the above search?

Comment: Whats your expected output?

Comment: The `.` is a metacharacter for any character. so, it should be escaped i.e. `U\\.S\\.`

Comment: correct @akrun. I was about to say the same. Google "escape regex"

Comment: Escaping the dot would not fix the problem. Besides, the [`\b` in `\bD\.S\.\b` would not match `D.S.` if not followed with a word char](https://regex101.com/r/LkjcQ9/1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should

1) escape the dot, 
 2) re-organize the regex to make sure it has no trailing `\b` as it would require a word char after a dot, it is more appropriate to use a `(?!\w)` negative lookahead in these cases (or, if you only want to match before whitespace or end of string, with `(?!\S)`).

Use

```
> x <- "This Dose was given to him in the U.S. on 16 June"
> pattern <- "\\b(?:Baseline|Table|U\\.S\\.|D\\.S\\.)(?!\\w)"
> str_extract_all(x, regex(pattern,ignore_case = TRUE))
[[1]]
[1] "U.S."
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LkjcQ9/2).

**Details**

- `\b` - a leading word boundary (as all the alternatives start with a word char, it is appropriate to use `\b`, else consider changing to `(?<!\w)` or `(?<!\S)`, negative lookaheads that fail the match if there is a word / non-whitespace char immediately to the left of the current location.)
- `(?:Baseline|Table|U\.S\.|D\.S\.)` - one of the alternative substrings, `Baseline`, `Table`, `U.S.` or D.S.`
- `(?!\w)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there is a word char immediately to the right of the current location.